# Import FBX Camera animation - rotation issue?

Tags: animation, camera, tracking, .fbx

I'm trying to import an animated (position and rotation) camera from a FBX file, however, when I do the animation is completely wrong and doesn't match the movement of the camera from the other program (Cinema 4D). I've tried exporting different versions of the FBX file (FBX 2011 - 2016) but the FBX version doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem. I think the position of the camera seems fine (however, I'm not really sure) but the rotation seems completely off. The scale seems to be correct since a 1 meter cube in the middle of the scene from C4D matches the size of adding a 1 meter cube in Blender. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is likely caused by C4D's different coordinate system. If I'm not mistaken it's right hand oriented, Y-axis is up and positive Z-axis is forward. You either need to adjust your export setting to use the proper coordinate system for Blender or adjust it in Blender's importer settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm coming from After Effects I can use this plugin to properly import a 3D camera to Blender: https://blendermarket.com/products/ae2blend